# Equation to calculate x and y speed for pen plotter to ensure constant pen speed

Tags: math, linear-algebra

I'm coding up software to control a pen plotter and I want my pen to move at a specific speed. I have two motors, one for x and one for y. I need to know how fast to run each to have the pen move at a speed value. This depends on how much change in x and y there is. I have the ability to run these motors for a distance amount and speed.

I would like to tell my plotter to move the pen from point a (x1,y1) to point b (x2,y2) at 100 units per second. I can't figure out how to calculate how many units per second to move the x and y motors to achieve the desired pen speed because the pen will be moving at an angle. This was a lot harder than I thought.

The code I'm working with

constants

```
PEN_VIRTUAL_COORDINATES_PER_SECOND = 7
MOTOR_UNITS_PER_VIRTUAL_COORDINATE_X = 3
MOTOR_UNITS_PER_VIRTUAL_COORDINATE_Y = 6
```

Integer variables. This is how many virtual coordinates the pen needs to move per step

```
delta_x
delta_y
```

Motor control interface
position is the motor unit distance to travel
speed is motor units per second

```
x_axis_motor.run_to_rel_pos(speed=, position=delta_y*MOTOR_UNITS_PER_VIRTUAL_COORDINATE_Y)
```

What I'm stuck on is calculating "speed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with the update on the used API of yours I see it like this. You got wanted speed `v [mm/s]` and deltas `dx,dy [mm]` to move and step sizes `mx,my [mm/step]` then:

[image: deltas]

so we know that:

```
a=atan2(dy,dx);
vx=abs(v*cos(a)/mx);
vy=abs(v*sin(a)/my);
```

where `vx,vy [step/s]` are the motors individual speeds and `[step/s]` is the same as frequency in `[Hz]`. Its just a Pythagorean triangle where the `[mm/s]` speeds ratios between **x,y** axises and whole speed `v` are the same as the triangle lengths so `sin,cos` apply to them in the same way. I just added the conversion `[mm/s] -> [step/s] = [Hz]`. I also `abs` the result as you deltas already have signs... For the same reason you can also use `atan` instead of `atan2`

```
a=atan(dy/dx);
```

but do not forget to handle the edge cases when `dx` is near `zero` !!!

In case your step sizes are inverted `[step/mm]` then you just multiply instead of divide by them.

Also in case you do not have goniometrics at your disposal or you do not want to use it you can use triangle similarity for that too:

```
l = sqrt( dx^2 + dy^2 )
sin(a) = dy/l
cos(a) = dx/l
```

so:

```
vx=abs((v*dx)/(l*mx));
vy=abs((v*dy)/(l*my));
```

which is computable also on integers and should be also faster and more precise to compute ... Again beware the division by zero (point instead of line) simply set the speed in such case (`l==0`) to zero for both axises.